# Combobox for Foreign Key in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a database containing two tables, Products and Licences. `Licences.ProductID` has a foreign key reference to `Products.ProductID` (i.e. licenses for that product).

How do I represent that relationship in a WinForms DataGridView?

When feeding the DataGridView (SQL Metal and through LINQ to SQL), the ProductLicences.ProductID, it automatically generates a column with a text field expecting a "Product" (which of course I can't enter...).

How do I change this column to contain a combobox listing the available products?

---

I have an connection (inherits from `Linq.DataContext`), the data source assigned to the DataGridView is a `Link.IQueryable`, generated as such:

```
var ds = from c in m_connection.Licences
    select c;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, the behaviour you are trying to imitate is a Lookup Combo.  You don't want to use the `Product` field of the `License` class, you actually want to use the `ProductID` field.

Here's a quick step-by-step:

1. Remove the `Product` column in the grid; keep only the `ProductID`.
2. Change the `ProductID` column's `ColumnType` property to **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn**.
3. Change this column's `DataSource` to a new `BindingSource` with the `DataSource` set to `MyProject.Product` (you can just follow the wizard, probably the same way you did it for the grid itself, but using `Product` instead of `License`).
4. Change the `DisplayMember` of this column to whatever text you want to show in the combo box, for example, `ProductName`.
5. Change the `ValueMember` to the actual primary key, such as `ProductID`.
6. **Before** populating the `GridView` itself, initialize the new `productsBindingSource` with product data, i.e. with `productBindingSource.DataSource = context.Products;`.

That's it.  Now when you `SubmitChanges` (assuming you kept the `DataContext` open the whole time), it will update the `ProductID` with the correct reference.  Note that it might not update the `Product` reference on the class that it saved; if you need to make use of the actual entity reference for any reason then you might need to call the `DataContext.Refresh` method on it first.  But don't worry about this unless you need to use the entity class outside the grid.

Comment: And what if the License class only has a Product field and not a ProductID field? (You shouldn't add an extra ProductID field just for UI binding purposes IMO)

Comment: @goku: Uh... what if the sky falls?  It's specified in the question that the field exists, and it's also explicit behaviour of Linq to SQL (also specified in the question).

Comment: When I tried to add a new row it throw exception : The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not
valid.
To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

Comment: @JatSing Please provide an inner exception details.

Comment: best answer I found on Internet. Thanks :)

Comment: Mind you this approach won't work with Linq 2 SQL or Entity Framework and simply setting the ID will only work for new entities. The SubmitChanges() in the context will throw an  error if you try to change the ProductID property of the entity for an entity loaded from the database. You have to set the Product property instead. And make sure the product datasource is populated from the same data context as your original data.

Comment: What I do is assign the event handler for the combobox select change event and update the product the same time user makes the selection. Which keeps the entity up to date.