# DataSet and ComboBox of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, dataset

I want to use `ComboBox` in the **PatientType column** of the editable `DataGridView`.
So I assumed to create `DataSet` and add basic table "Patients" and  "PatientTypes" table as well.

Do I need to make more changes in the `DataSet` to achieve my goal?

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Patients");
table1.Columns.Add("Id");
table1.Columns.Add("Name");
table1.Columns.Add("PatientTypeId");
table1.Rows.Add("sam", 1, 1);
table1.Rows.Add("mark", 2, 2);

DataTable table2 = new DataTable("PatientTypes");
table2.Columns.Add("id");
table2.Columns.Add("Name");
table2.Rows.Add(1, "rich");
table2.Rows.Add(2, "poor");

// Create a DataSet and put both tables in it.
DataSet set = new DataSet("Office");
set.Tables.Add(table1);
set.Tables.Add(table2);
```

Comment: It depend on how you will use it. You need use PatientsTypes table as DataSOurce of ComboboxColumn. Actually you can do it even without DataTable

Comment: @Fabio Sounds good! Would you mind to pioint me to some example? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combobox for Foreign Key in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256924/combobox-for-foreign-key-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created some sample app to see how it should work.
Here is full code of WinForm app.

```
namespace DataGridAndComboBox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Users> users = new List<Users>();

        List<Months> months = new List<Months>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += DataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
            Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            months.Add(new Months() { ID = 1, Name = "Jan" });
            months.Add(new Months() { ID = 2, Name = "Feb" });
            months.Add(new Months() { ID = 3, Name = "Mar" });


            users.Add(new Users() { ID = 1, MonthID = 1, Name = "Trump" });
            users.Add(new Users() { ID = 2, MonthID = 2, Name = "Clinton" });
            users.Add(new Users() { ID = 3, MonthID = 3, Name = "Obama" });
            users.Add(new Users() { ID = 4, MonthID = 1, Name = "Reygan" });
            users.Add(new Users() { ID = 5, MonthID = 2, Name = "Kennedi" });
            users.Add(new Users() { ID = 6, MonthID = 3, Name = "Bush" });

        }

        //Get data from database
        private void ButtonGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bindingSourceMonths = new BindingSource()
            {
                DataSource = months
            };

            #region Create DataGridView columns

            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

            var userID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                HeaderText = "ID user",
                Width = 50,
                DataPropertyName = "ID",
                Name = "ID"
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(userID);

            var userName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                HeaderText = "User Name",
                Width = 100,
                DataPropertyName = "Name",
                Name = "Name"
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(userName);


            var userMonthID = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
            {
                HeaderText = "Month",
                Width = 100,
                DataPropertyName = "MonthID",
                DataSource = bindingSourceMonths,
                ValueMember = "ID",
                DisplayMember = "Name",
                Name = "MonthID"
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(userMonthID);

            #endregion

            dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
        }

        //Update database
        private void ButtonUpdateData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var userID = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                var userName = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                var userMonthID = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                var m = months.First(x => x.ID == userMonthID);
            }
        } 

        private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "MonthID")
            {
                Users users = (Users)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;  

                var monthName = months.First(x => x.ID == users.MonthID);
            }
        }
    }


    #region Classes

    public class Months
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Users
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int MonthID { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to make more changes to the dataSet, but you do need to set up your DataGridView to have a combobox column that has:

- the .DataPropertyName property set to what column of Patients you want the combobox to edit, probably "PatientTypeId"
- the .DataSource property set to your PatientType datatable
- the .DisplayMember property set to what you want the combo to show, probably "name"
- the .ValueMember property set to what you want the combobox to use as a value for PatientTypeId, probably "id"

I post this advice even though Fabio already linked to a good related article because that article uses typed datasets and visual designer for datagridview so it might be hard to adapt the advice it gives to your situation

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and set its `DataSource` , `HeaderText` , `Name` , `DataPropertyName` , `ValueMember` , `DisplayMember` properties

and then add this to your datagridview's `Columns`

Below is the code (tested with your sample data)

```
var comboBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboBox.DataSource = dataset.Tables["PatientTypes"];
    comboBox.HeaderText = "PatientTypeId";
    comboBox.Name = "PatientTypeId";
    comboBox.DataPropertyName = "PatientTypeId"; //important
    comboBox.ValueMember = "id";
    comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboBox);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables["Patients"];
// set the column poition in the grid same as table
dataGridView1.Columns["PatientTypeId"].DisplayIndex = dataset.Tables["Patients"].Columns["PatientTypeId"].Ordinal;
```