# how to show combobox in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, windows-forms-core

Hello everyone I have two Tables named `Brand(Id,Name)` and `Product(Id,BrandId,Name)`, I want showing Product list in `DataGridView(Id,Name,Brand)`, `Brand Column` should be `ComboBox` that refer to `BrandId` in `Product Table` and shows `Name Of Brand` from records in `Brand` table

How can do it

Brand Table

[image]

Product Table

[image]

DataGridView

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? *"I want to do X, show me how"* is not a question for SO. There's plenty of information out there on a basic subject like this. Look for it, follow it and post back if and when you encounter an actual issue.

Comment: This answer should drive you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256924/combobox-for-foreign-key-in-datagridview?rq=1

Comment: show 3 empty rows in `datagrid` @Steve

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create and populate DataTable

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Brand", typeof(string));

// Populate it here

// With this once we set datasource of dgv, it will not generate columns automatically
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn idCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "Id",
    HeaderText = "Id",
    DataPropertyName = "Id",
    Width = 50,
    HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell()
    {
        Value = "Id"
    }
};

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nameCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "Name",
    HeaderText = "Name",
    DataPropertyName = "Name",
    Width = 200,
    HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell()
    {
        Value = "Name"
    }
};

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn brandCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "Brand",
    HeaderText = "Brand",
    DataPropertyName = "Brand",
    Width = 100,
    HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell()
    {
        Value = "Brand"
    },
    DataSource = new List<Tuple<int, string>>() {
        new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Brand 1"),
        new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Brand 2"),
        new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Brand 3")
    },
    DisplayMember = "Item2",
    ValueMember = "Item1"
};

// Now we add these columns to our dgv
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(idCol);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(nameCol);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(brandCol);

// and at last, we bind our data to it
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

You can see that column which is our `ComboBox` use same binding system as normal combobox. For this purposle I used list of tuples to populate it, but you would normally load data from database for that part.

Lets say you have Brand class like this:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // important to be property, not variable
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You load data from database and create list of these objects:

```
// I have done it manually
List<Brand> brandsList = new List<Brand>();
brandsList.Add(new Brand() { ID = 1, Name = "Brand 1 });
brandsList.Add(new Brand() { ID = 2, Name = "Brand 2 });
brandsList.Add(new Brand() { ID = 3, Name = "Brand 3 });
```

Then you would change upper combobox column definition to:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn brandCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "Brand",
    HeaderText = "Brand",
    DataPropertyName = "Brand",
    Width = 100,
    HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell()
    {
        Value = "Brand"
    },
    DataSource = brandsList,
    DisplayMember = "Name",
    ValueMember = "ID"
};
```

Comment: Everything is written from head, without testing. If there is some error please write in comment, I will quickfix it